# Port 3000 is already in use

Tags: node.js

Node.js の Express.js において

```
node bin\www
```

でアプリを起動、つまりサーバを起動したのですが、
ファイルを編集したのち、一度サーバを閉じてもう一度立ち上げたいというときに `^C` でもサーバを閉じることができず、

```
Port 3000 is already in use
```

というエラーが出ます。

**補足**

```
npm install express-session
```

をした後に閉じられなくなったので、関係があると思います。

**環境**
OS：Windows10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

既存のプロセスがバックグラウンドに残っているのが原因だと思われますが、手っ取り早くは OS 自体を再起動してから改めて node のプロセスを起動してみてください。

Comment: 再起動したら、サーバの起動と停止ができるようになりました。

Comment: Express.js をインストールして初めてサーバを立てる場合にはこのエラーが発生すると思われます。

Answer (score 1):

### 考えられる原因

おそらく、起動したプロセスがバックグランドで実行されてしまったからでしょう。

### 対処方法

強制終了の手順をここでは示します。
まずはPORT 3000を利用しているプロセスを確認します。

```sh
lsof -i:3000
```

次のような表示になるかと思います。

```
COMMAND  PID          USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node    5298     USER_NAME   23u  IPv6 0xe3f203e22022bc12      0t0  TCP *:hbci (LISTEN)
```

PIDの番号をコピーし、強制終了します。

```
kill -9 5298
```

これらを行なったあと、expressを再度起動してみてください。

### 参考

- https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1904/18/news033.html

Comment: Windows を使用しているのですが、これって Unix のコマンドですか？

Comment: おっと、これは失礼ました...見逃してました

Comment: @Toru Egawa さん、@himenon さん、Windowsなら調べるのはCUIのnetstat [netstatでリッスンしているプロセスを特定する](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/0207/30/news002.html) で、終了させるのはGUIのタスクマネージャー [Windows10で応答しなくなったアプリを強制終了する方法（タスクマネージャー）](https://4thsight.xyz/9388) か、CUIのTaskKill [Windows10で強制的にタスクを終了する方法](https://toolmania.info/post-8960/) ですね。

Comment: @kunif さんありがとうございます。@Toru Egawa さん、もし[WSL](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/wsl/install-win10)などの機能を利用する機会があればlsofコマンドなど利用できるかと思います。

Comment: @himeron さん  環境についてはご指摘いただいてから追記しました。